# salesforce.com plugin for website

Tags: php, database, salesforce, plugins

There is a company that uses salesforce software to keep track of all customers and the performance of the employees. I am building a points website, which is about the manager rewarding points to employees for a job well done. I want to integrate the info from salesforce software database about the employees and present it on my website so that the manager can see the number of deals closed by each employee and accordingly allocate points to that person. is there any kind of a plug-in or something like that? if not, how can i achieve this?  My website is a cms, built on php.

Thanks.

Comment: Make sure to confirm with the client if there's API access to their environment (for example you're safe if they are paying for Enterprise or Unlimited edition. Or if they know they can use Data Loader, Outlook plugin etc.). Otherwise you will probably be up to some horrible screen scraping...

Comment: Well i do not know right now if the client has enterprise edition or not but most probably they would not be making 500 calls to the api per day. is it 500 calls to the api per day per email/password combination or 500 calls to the api on my website?

Comment: 500 calls to Salesforce, per user, per day; not per calling website/program. You need to provide user credentials (or user's session id if he's already logged in to salesforce) so the usage will be counted against "this" user. As for callouts from salesforce to your env: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_gov_limits.htm (look for HTTP stuff, basically it says up to 10 calls to your website per user action like clicking a button. So no real daily limit, just your performance).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to handle this situation is to import the enterprise or partner WSDL into your PHP CMS. This will enable you to make webservice calls to Salesforce.com and access almost all of the data sitting on the Salesforce.com server.

It'll also enable you to write back to Salesforce.com servers. There is very good documentation and code samples out there try this link first:

http://wiki.developerforce.com/index.php/Web_Services_API#PHP

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [PHP Toolkit](http://wiki.developerforce.com/index.php/PHP_Toolkit), which is a PHP wrapper around the [salesforce API](http://wiki.developerforce.com/index.php/Web_Services_API#PHP).

Answer (score 0):

Be aware, there are some quirks and it's some bulky functionality.  Salesforce limits the amount of hits you can have on the webservice, so you may need to do a cron-based "grab" of info and store to your site at various intervals.  You'll get a rude awakening when you're testing and run out of connections for the day (not applicable to people who pay the premium level of Salesforce)  It's also rather slow and has a propensity to timeout often....so be prepared to write code to handle the exceptions that will be caused.

Your server will need to have CURL installed and properly functioning.

Good luck!

Comment: Well thisis what i am planning on doing. I will write a code on my website asking the user to enter his email address & password for the salesforce website. Then I will write queries, whose tables will be taken from the SF database and show it on my webpage. Is this possible. I know abt the 500 web service call limit for normal edition of SF, but does my logic even work if i try to implement it?

Comment: well, it's not exactly as you describe.  My experience is that each account gets one API key, giving you access to the info that's on that account's database.  So, if you were to set it up as one company with 50 sales people, for example, you'd have access to all 50 with that one API key, and then it's just a matter of asking the webservice for the correct data.  In our example, we query SF on 4 hour increments to update our data with their data.  Since our's isn't required to be realtime, we get the info and stuff in our own DB rather than relying on them to function every time.